# Execute R script with python subprocess.call

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I want to execute a R script from a python script using:

subprocess.call("Rscript script.R --args arg1 arg2", shell=True)

How do I have to write my script.R in order to use the args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `commandArgs` like this:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

arg1 <- args[1]
arg2 <- args[2]
[...your code...]
```

Also make sure that the `Rscript` executable is in your `PATH`.